# What was Rian Johnson's influence on Bloodline?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, star-wars-bloodline

In the lead-up to *Star Wars: The Last Jedi*, the great book *Bloodline*, by Claudia Gray, was released. It became notable for supposedly having Rian Johnson's input on it. This was later revealed to be some communication between the Lucasfilm Story Group and Gray. However, there was still some input there. What was it, now that Episode VIII is out?